# Why is a 0.001uF capacitor in parallel with the base-emitter of this transistors?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, decoupling-capacitor

I am trying to analyze a digital circuit. In this circuit, there are several BJT transistors, some for back-light LED driving, some for switching and etc. Almost all of transistor has a 1nF MLCC capacitor connected from base to GND. It seems they are *decoupling capacitor*, but I am not sure. I really need a reason for this type of design. I asked some people. One of them said this capacitor protects the base of transistor, specially for preventing of unknown switch operating or BCI protecting. (Highlighted capacitors in below picture)
[image]

Comment: What's BCI stand for? And a full schematic is required. The context of what's driving the transistor is needed.

Comment: 1nF == .001 uF, not .1 uF

Comment: As stated above, a full schematic is required. But note that if you have an input coming from "outside world" then you should place a capacitor to protect that input. Besides, BCI (Bulk Current Injection) test is performed on any input and output coming from/going to "outside world" via a cable and I'm not sure a single capacitor would be sufficient for BCI protection.

Comment: Those are fairly odd places for capacitors. Maybe to reduce EMI from PWM?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Shown LED is drived by MCU(micro-controller) PWM signal. Then, what is your mean from "EMI from PWM"?

Comment: Q1, C1 and R1 forms a simple current limiter with 600mV / 51ohm = 12mA of current limit. C1 and R1 forms and LPF with  cut-off frequency of 3.1MHz. R5 and C2 forms and LPF with cut-off frequency of 48kHz.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Yes, It is a current limitter, but what happened if i don't use C1 capacitor? This question is also applied to C2.

Comment: I'm assuming it's too prevent too much oscillation by the circuit. Or hysterics.

Comment: @RohatKılıç should we place a LPF always in BJT bases? if yes, how we should define best cut-off frequency? I see this cap is used in K-LINes too.

Comment: @Passerby Can you explain your mean more?

Comment: @Araz If you don't use either C1 or C2 or both, the circuit will work with no problems. C1 reduces EMI coming from PWM due to switching action of Q2 and load. In my designs, I place such LPFs with a cut-off frequency of about (5 x fsw).

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thank you, How you know that 5 x fsw is a good cut-off frequency? have you any technical source for it?

Comment: We don't know what else the MCU pin is doing. If it's also part of an SPI interface or something, it could get busy for a millisecond now and again, in which case the capacitor may reduce flicker or unwanted switching activity

Comment: @Araz No, I don't have any technical source for it, but I can say that 5 x fsw does not change rise and fall times of the signal a lot -depending on the frequency, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a circuit to limit BOTH edges on a relatively high voltage (12V) signal controlled by (presumably) PWM output from MCU. This is a quick LTspice simulation of the circuit:

[image]

Edges are reduced to about 1us rise and fall time. Funny part is that removing of C1 or increasing it to 1uF has no effect on any edge, it is fully defined by C2.

Comment: "it is fully defined by C2" -- not surprisingly, since the command pulse must first pass through R4-C2, C1 being only for protection. Actually this is what doesn't make much sense to me: the protection should act immediately, not delayed, so C1 shouldn't be there, but maybe there's a hidden purpouse that I don't see.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen What you purpose for immediate protection here? TVS or VDR is a expensive solution for this situation.

Comment: Actually, the OP's  question (in first edition) was specifically about the purpose of C1.

Comment: @AliChen Would you give me its URL address please?

Comment: Do you mean the free LTspice tool? http://ltspice.linear-tech.com/software/LTspiceXVII.exe

Comment: @AliChen I mean "the OP's question (in first edition) ". :)

Comment: You should be able to access "edited yesterday" http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/261063/revisions